# A block inside a block in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to do a text, a line and then a button like the following image:
[image]
I have this code and the functionality works fine but the css is wrong:

```
{ retrospectives.size > 0 &&
  <div className='c-division-line u-margin-bottom'>
    <h3>
      <span> Last Retrospectives </span>
    </h3>
  </div>
}
{ retrospectives.size > 4 &&
  <div className="c-division-line__button u-font-size--12px">
    <RetroLink project={projectId} path={path}/>
  </div>
}
```

Now, If I do this (a block of code inside other block) the css is correct but the functionality fails. How can I do this where both the css and functionality works fine?

```
{ retrospectives.size > 0 &&
  <div className='c-division-line u-margin-bottom'>
    <h3>
      <span> Last Retrospectives </span>
    </h3>
    { retrospectives.size > 4 &&
      <div className="c-division-line__button u-font-size--12px">
        <RetroLink project={projectId} path={path}/>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
}
```

I thought about doing the following function but it didn't work:

```
  buttonLink () {
    const { retrospectives, projectId, path } = this.props
    if (retrospectives.size > 4) {
      return <div className="c-division-line__button u-font-size--12px">
        <RetroLink project={projectId} path={path}/>
      </div>
    }
  }
```

And calling it like this
{this.buttonLink()}

Comment: are you trying to return different components? or is it a conditional component under a parent component which is in a conditional aswell?

Comment: it a conditional component under a parent component which is in a conditional aswell? @xSkrappy

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making your button element into a variable, like this:

```
const allRetrospectivesButton = retrospectives.size > 4 && (
     <div className="c-division-line__button u-font-size--12px">
         <RetroLink project={projectId} path={path}/>
     </div>
);

return retrospectives.size > 0 && (
     <div className='c-division-line u-margin-bottom'>
         <h3>
             <span> Last Retrospectives </span>
         </h3>
         { allRetrospectivesButton }
     </div>
);
```